# Django navbar view changed and unstable

Tags: django, static, navbar

```html
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "bootstrap-4.5.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}">



    <!--Navbar Starts Here-->
    {% include 'navbar.html' %}
    <!--Navbar Ends-->

    {% block headContent %}{% endblock headContent%}

    <style>
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 100% ;
            }
            th, td {
                border: 1px solid #dddddd;
                text-align: left;
                padding: 8px;
            }

            tr:nth-child(even) {
                background-color: #f2f2f2
            }

            tr:hover {
                background-color: #dddddd
            }
        </style>

    {% block stylesheet %}{% endblock %}

  </head>
  <div class="container">
    <body>

      <h2>{% block title %}
      {% endblock title %}</h2>

      {% block content %}
      {% endblock content%}


      <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
      <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
      <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
      <script src="{% static "jquery-3.5.1.min.js" %}"></script>
      <script src="{% static "bootstrap-4.5.2-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" %}"></script>
      <script>
        var testStatuses = document.getElementsByClassName('testStatus');
        for (var i = 0; i < testStatuses.length; i++ ){
            if( testStatuses[i].innerHTML == 0 ){
                testStatuses[i].innerHTML = "Not Requested";
            } else if( testStatuses[i].innerHTML == 1){
                testStatuses[i].innerHTML = "Requested";
            } else if (testStatuses[i].innerHTML == 2) {
                testStatuses[i].innerHTML = "Processing";
            } else if (testStatuses[i].innerHTML == 3) {
                testStatuses[i].innerHTML = "Processed";
            } else if (testStatuses[i].innerHTML == 4) {
                testStatuses[i].innerHTML = "Results";
            } else if (testStatuses[i].innerHTML == 5) {
                testStatuses[i].innerHTML = "Reviewed";
            }
        }
      </script>
      {% block javascript %}{% endblock %}

    </body>
  </div>
</html>
```

```html
<!--Navbar Starts Here-->


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light mb-4" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">VISL HIV</a>


  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>


      {% if user.is_superuser %}
      <!-- <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/admin">Administration <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li> -->

      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Administration</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/admin/auth/group/">Groups</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/admin/auth/user/">Users</a>

        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
          <!--<a class="nav-link" href="/admin/vigilant/sample/">Samples<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>-->
          <a class="nav-link" href="/samples">Samples<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/personal">Personal<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item active">
         <!-- <a class="nav-link" href="/admin/vigilant/order/">Orders<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> -->
          <a class="nav-link" href="/tests">Tests<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/mutations">Mutations<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/sequences">Sequences<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      {% endif %}


      {% if user.is_authenticated %}

      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Data Extraction</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/PatientSearch">Patient search</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/MutationSearch">mutation search</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/CladeSearch">Clade search</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/SampleDateSearch">Sample Date Search</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/NIHIDSearch">NIH ID Search</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      {% endif %}

    </ul>
    <a class="nav-link" href="/help">Help<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                {{user.username}}
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/TBD">My Tasks</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout">Logout</a>
            </div>
          </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0"  action="#" method='GET'>
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" name='q' aria-label="Search" placeholder='Search' value={{request.GET.q}}  >
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    {% else %}
      <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="/login">Login</a>
      <!-- <a class="btn btn-primary ml-2 mr-2" href="#">Register</a> -->
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</nav>
<!--Navbar Ends-->
```

[I supposed to have the navbar like the this. but when I first runserver with my appA, it always show the navbar like a list menu, like the figure 2. If I run another appB runserver and rerun myapp A, the navbar goes normal like figure1. So it looks like if I want to get the normal Navbar in appA, I should first run anther appB and then I can get the normal navbar for appA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXc2U.jpg)

[This is the navbar what I get if I run appA first after I open my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPDMb.jpg). Thak you very much for any kind suggestions. It looks like the problem of static.

Comment: You should post the code from your template.  Your question is not answerable in it's current format.

Comment: Thank you for you nice notice. I will add my code in my question. Thank you.

Comment: The problem would appear to be how you are including (or not including) bootstrap.  Are you using a CDN link?  Is it places in your base template file?  I'm not sure which version of bootstrap you're using, but check the installation instructions, like these: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/download/.  Also you may have an out-of-place </ul> tag, I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice suggestion. I put the base html in my post. Would you please have a look it. I really appreciate that. The base.html and navbar.html in the two app are same. AppA works good. Appb only works good after I run AppA, otherwise, If I open AppB first in webpage, it returun the list of the menu. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by AppA and AbbB.  Are those apps within your django application structure?

Comment: Sorry for the confusing information, AppA and AbbB are two django projects. I just name them AppA and AppB. They have same setting and templates html. However just one webpage navvar shows like a list. while the another one works good.

Comment: Sounds like you are not loading bootstrap correctly.  You should replicate your code from the working app in the non-working app.

Comment: I really appreciate your nice suggestion. Yes, I do replicated the code, however, I have no idea where it is wrong.